# Dynamically get the name of form under sub menu vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have MenuStrip and SubMenus on my project.
How do I dynamically get the name of the form just by identifying the name of the subMenu

Example : I have HelpToolStripMenuItem , under this HelpToolStripMenuItem_Click my code is frmHelp.showdialog

Question : How do I get my form Name which is "frmHelp" just by identifying my HelpToolStripMenuItem name and without clicking the menu itself ?

I hope someone can help me . Thank you !

Comment: You don't.  There is no inherent relationship between the menu item and the form.  Perhaps you should explain what you're actually trying to achieve rather than how you're trying to achieve it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I'm trying to create a user restriction module . My idea is show all the menus, after that, the admin will select which menus are only accessible with the particular user . when menus are already selected , my plan is to get the form name and get the objects inside of that form so that the admin can also restrict the user for clicking buttons inside of that form .

Comment: It sounds like the logical thing to do is create a `Dictionary` where the menu items are the keys and the forms are the values.  It's something you would have to do explicitly because, as i said, there is no implicit relationship based on what you're already doing.  Another option might be to use the `Tag` of the menu items but, depending on how you're actually configuring the permissions, I'd consider that a second choice.